# Can we send the follow up emails on the already send system email?

Tags: scheduled-apex, apex-email-service, time-dependent-workflow

I have a requirement, as per which the system sends an email notification in each quarter to the Account contact for some document submission. Now, the system has to send a follow email after every 7 days till the docs are submitted. Do we have any way be which the system can refer to the first mail which has been send to the user and send a follow email on the same mail chain.

Please let me know, if any one has any idea of how this can be implemented.

Thanks in Advance!